# Grub rescue; "no such device" error happens Intermittently

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation

I have three storage devices:

- `/dev/sda`, an SSD with Windows 8 installed on it (NTFS)
- `/dev/sdb`, an HDD with a single NTFS partition on it that is shared
- `/dev/sdc`, an SSD with Ubuntu 13.10 installed on it as a single EXT4 partition

About 50% of the time when I reboot, usually to switch the OS, I see the following:

```
error: no such device: <uuid>
entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Where `<uuid>` is the UUID of /dev/sdc1. When it happens, it goes away if I press Ctrl+Alt+Del and go into my BIOS's boot menu and choose /dev/sda to boot from.

The intermittent behavior and the fact that it goes away only through that method (i.e. reinstalling GRUB to /dev/sda as other Ask Ubuntu answers recommend does not help) makes me think this is unrelated to the dozens of other AU questions about the same error message. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: See if there are any differences between rebooting and booting from off. It seems like your HDD or SSD is either not powering on/mounting in time, or somehow managed by the BIOS.

Comment: The issue appears to happen 100% of the time from a cold boot, but again, can be sidestepped by forcing a boot device from the BIOS menu.

Answer (score 3):

I got it fixed by **disabling "Fast Boot" in BIOS** settings

i had the same issue with dual boot (Win 10/Ubuntu ) with GRUB reporting "no such device" when shutting down from Ubuntu

some also recommend disabling Secure Boot but i didn't have that enabled here

i think this is similar to this issue:

https://superuser.com/questions/1114863/grub-fails-boot-with-no-such-device-sometimes/1192805

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same situation here:

- SSD (Kingston 480GB) mounted on two partitions (kubuntu 14.04):

  - `/dev/sda1` (ext2) with `/boot`
  - `/dev/sda3` (ext4) with `/`
- SSD (Crucial M4 256GB) mounted on `/dev/sdc` (ntfs) with windows 7 (it's a mSATA)
- HDD (WD 750GB) mounted on `/dev/sdb` (ntfs) shared with the two OS.

On a cold boot it always your same error, but only one time.
To have it work properly it's enough to reboot or to press the manual boot selection.
The uuid in the error it's the one from the `/dev/sda1` partition (`/boot`).
The MBR is on the `/dev/sda`, and I've tried to boot only with the windows'SSD and it never showed the same problem.
Maybe, like Mr.Lee suggests, it only need some moment to power after the boot's automatic start.
I'll update you in case something change (for better or  for worse).